# E/paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR -PayPal Integration (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, paypal-sandbox

I need to integrate PayPal payment in my mobile app. But /paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR occur

When I try to login a sandbox account, this occur:
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoZRf.png)
I tried 3-4 paypal sandbox accounts and change password of those accounts, the result still the same.

And this is the error in IDE:

```
`E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:503,exception:
    Exception parsing server response
    org.json.JSONException: could not parse:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>503 backend read error</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Error 503 backend read error</h1>
        <p>backend read error</p>
        <h3>Guru Mediation:</h3>
        <p>Details: cache-hnd18733-HND 1635445420 2826081677</p>
        <hr>
        <p>Varnish cache server</p>
      </body>
    </html>
    
    nextValue:<?xml
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cw.m(Unknown Source:45)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.fm.d(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.ci.a(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.a(Unknown Source:62)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cq.onResponse(Unknown Source:45)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    request failed with server response:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>503 backend read error</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Error 503 backend read error</h1>
        <p>backend read error</p>
        <h3>Guru Mediation:</h3>
        <p>Details: cache-hnd18733-HND 1635445420 2826081677</p>
        <hr>
        <p>Varnish cache server</p>
      </body>
    </html>
E/paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

`

I am using this PayPal Android SDK version:

```
implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
```

Here is my code:

```
 private val clientKey = "AQ3wVxWOVjRThzrB67mop4VNe18YkqB_vJdyVddpUNzzsN9SqNncpUJ_BLoUNkhTd213Cc8odVldU6op"
private val PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 123
private val config = PayPalConfiguration() // Start with mock environment.  When ready,
    // switch to sandbox (ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
    // or live (ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
    .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX) // on below line we are passing a client id.
    .clientId(clientKey)
```

In onCreate():

```
val intent = Intent(this, PayPalService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config)
    startService(intent)



binding.btnPay.setOnClickListener{

             getPayment()
}
```

Override method :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode === RESULT_OK) {
        val confirm: PaymentConfirmation = data!!.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION)!!
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4))

                // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                // see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                // for more details.
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e)
            }
        }
    } else if (resultCode === RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.")
    } else if (resultCode === PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
        Log.i(
            "paymentExample",
            "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs."
        )
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    stopService(Intent(this, PayPalService::class.java))
    super.onDestroy()
}

private fun getPayment() {
    //Getting the amount from editText


    //Creating a paypalpayment
    val payment = PayPalPayment(
        BigDecimal(java.lang.String.valueOf("5.0")), "USD", "Testing",
        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE
    )

    //Creating Paypal Payment activity intent
    val intent = Intent(this, PaymentActivity::class.java)

    //putting the paypal configuration to the intent
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config)

    //Puting paypal payment to the intent
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment)

    //Starting the intent activity for result
    //the request code will be used on the method onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are attempting to use the deprecated [PayPal-Android-SDK.](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK)

Use the current [Native Checkout SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/).